Iframe with html is refreshing itself after a submission. In original html this is not occuring
In newsletter.html (lets call that my file) I have created a newsletter, user submits an email, then its in my JSON file.
I have my homepage.html, I put iframe from newsletter.html, it all working, except after I submit my email, page refreshes itself in no time.
This is a video: https://gyazo.com/d67ec1745e2ee041380c98d836403f82
I do not know how to prevent that.
The only thing that will prevent iframe automatically from reloading the page its this:
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.returnValue = '';

  
});

But this creates a window alert about reloading the page. I tried to disable that window alert, but I dont think that is a possibility.
So my desired outcome is to prevent iframe from reloading after successful submission. I want my iframe to display this 'Thanks ${emailName} for signing up!'. Ideally I would want my iframe to display this for like 5 seconds and that just disappear but I can life without it.
In newsletter.html its working like I want it to work, so I have gathered that its must be the iframe
I tried to write some js code in my homepage.js, but it did not work.
This is my html.
   <div class="container23">
      <iframe id="iframe2" src="http://localhost:3000"></iframe>
      <button type="button" id="close-button" class="close-button">&times;</button>
  </div>

Thanks.

Is using Ajax a possibility?

The iframe is not reloading the page: the web server is sending back a replacement page for the browser to display instead of the form submission page. You have options to make the server send back a "Thank you" page based on the uploaded data (which currently doesn't seem to include username)  - or upload  the newsletter sign-up data by posting it using fetch or similar methodology and using the response status or content to thank the user in front end code. What do you want to do?

... if you choose to continue with form submission to send data to the server, make sure you have a suitable action form attribute value. For security reasons of privacy set the method attribute value to POST and do not use the default GET value.

@itgoldman
Nothing seems to work, I tried using ajax but it does not work, or maybe I am using it wrong, I am beginner. I can manipulate with what I have with my iframe, so maybe I can work with that.
This "'Thanks ${emailName} for signing up!'" always worked. But in iframe its displayed for like 0.5 seconds. its in the video: This is a video: https://gyazo.com/d67ec1745e2ee041380c98d836403f82
What I want, is that page is not refreshed after that moment,
https://i.gyazo.com/38db9475c5e404c443691e93ea41bb34.png

@traktor
Part of my code of the content inside of iframe.
fetch('/subscribe', {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
body: JSON.stringify({ email: email })
})
.then(response =&gt; response.json())
.then(data =&gt; {
console.log('Response from server:', data);

if (data.success) {
responseMessage.textContent = 'Thanks ${emailName} for singing up!';
responseMessage.style.color = '#9320a7';
submitButton.disabled = true;
submitButton.style.display = 'none';
input.style.display = 'none';
ukryj.style.display = 'none';


Readers can't provide feedback on the iframe's behavior as shown in the video because all we know about it is that the code URL is http://localhost:3000. Please edit the question to supply more details about the problem and share code that it is causing it.  (Note code to share goes in the question itself, not in comments.) I recommend reading How do I ask a good question? on the help center before updating the post.

@traktor I found a solution, and answered myself, however I dont really understand why my solution is working.

If you are using a form to submit the information, adjust the attributes in the  accordingly; that is if you want your form to submit the data in the form to some endpoint directly, without manipulation. In this case, you can also set the form's button type to "submit"
In case you don't want to submit the data to some endpiint directly, just set the button's type to "button", access the form's data throught FormData class and manipulate it.
Giving a brief about  attributes here:
1. action:
•   Specifies the URL to which the form data should be sent when the form is submitted.
•   Example: <form action="/submit-form">
2.  method:
•   Defines the HTTP method to be used when sending form data. Common values are GET and POST.
•   GET appends the form data to the URL, visible in the browser’s address bar.
•   POST sends the form data in the body of the request, not visible in the URL.
•   Example: <form method="POST">


I fixed it. However, I dont understand why its working. Probably some part of my code was interfering with event.preventDefault();.
I deleted:
<head>

content stays
</head>

and
<body>

content stays
</body>

from homepage.html (I have my iframe there), and now everythign is working how I want it to work.
More information is available on https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/1e984se/iframe_with_html_is_refreshing_itself_after_a/
